How do you get the collectible under the submarine in stage 'Arctic'?
One of the 'hidden' collectibles in the Arctic stage is underwater, directly below the icebreaker/submarine.  However, it's floating some distance off the ground, and with no ramps or other bumps nearby I can't figure out how to collect it.


The solution was a bit simpler than I imagined.  There is a ridge on one side that seems pretty far from the token, but if you boost off the cliff as shown you can collect it!

